# Unknown Uri which causes more problems (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, fatal-error

I have been trying to solve this for a long time. I will post what i think is enough if you need anymore info then please ask me.

```
public class PInfoProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private PInfoDatabase mOpenHelper;

    private static String TAG = PInfoProvider.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

    private static final int PINFOS = 100;
    private static final int PINFOS_ID = 101;

    private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher(){
        final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        final String authority = PInfoContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;
        matcher.addURI(authority, "PInfos", PINFOS);
        matcher.addURI(authority, "Pinfos/*", PINFOS_ID);
        return matcher;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        mOpenHelper = new PInfoDatabase(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    private void deleteDatabase(){
        mOpenHelper.close();
        PInfoDatabase.deleteDatabase(getContext());
        mOpenHelper = new PInfoDatabase(getContext());
    }
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.setTables(PInfoDatabase.Tables.PInfo);

        switch(match){
            case PINFOS:
                //do nothing
                break;
            case PINFOS_ID:
                String id = PInfoContract.PInfos.getPInfoId(uri);
                queryBuilder.appendWhere(BaseColumns._ID + "=" + id);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }

        Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        //projection in content provider means the list of columns you want to return.
        return cursor;

    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        switch(match){
            case PINFOS:
                return PInfoContract.PInfos.CONTENT_TYPE;
            case PINFOS_ID:
                return PInfoContract.PInfos.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        //ContentValues: is a list of content values of our database such as the email and username. Contains the column names and the values we want to associate to it when we're writing to the database/
        Log.v(TAG, "insert(uri=" + uri + ", values =" + values.toString());

        final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

        switch(match){
            //only using the PInfo and not the ID becuase it's to insert only.
            case PINFOS:
                long recordID = db.insertOrThrow(PInfoDatabase.Tables.PInfo, null, values);
                return PInfoContract.PInfos.buildPInfoUri(String.valueOf(recordID));
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Log.v(TAG, "delete(uri=" + uri);

        if(uri.equals(PInfoContract.URI_TABLE)){
            deleteDatabase();
            return 0;
            //This will be executed if the user didn't input a valid record id.
            //Base content uri doesn't contain an ID nor a path.
        }
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

        String selectionCriteria = selection;

        switch(match){

            /*
            case PInfo:
                If this was called and didn't "break" it would change all the records in the table.
                We will still leave it out because we added the database deletion code above.
                 break;
             */

            case PINFOS_ID:
                String id = PInfoContract.PInfos.getPInfoId(uri);
                selectionCriteria = BaseColumns._ID + "=" + id
                        + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? "AND (" + selection + ")" : "");
                return db.delete(PInfoDatabase.Tables.PInfo, selectionCriteria, selectionArgs);

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Log.v(TAG, "update(uri=" + uri + ", values =" + values.toString());

        final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

        String selectionCriteria = selection;
        //We set selectionCriteria to equal selection in the case PInfo case was chosen. After all,
        //we still need to record the selection.

        switch(match){
            case PINFOS:
                //do nothing
                //If this was called and didn't "break" it would change all the records in the table.
                break;
            case PINFOS_ID:
                String id = PInfoContract.PInfos.getPInfoId(uri);
                selectionCriteria = BaseColumns._ID + "=" + id
                    + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? "AND (" + selection + ")" : "");
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }
        return db.update(PInfoDatabase.Tables.PInfo, values, selectionCriteria, selectionArgs);
    }
}
```

and the other class mentioned in the logcat:

```
public class AddActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    private final String LOG_TAG = AddActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private TextView mWebsiteTextView, mEmailTextView, mUsernameTextView, mPasswordTextView;
    private Button mButton;
    private ContentResolver mContentResolver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_edit);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //returns up one level rather than back to the top level

        mWebsiteTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pinfoWebsite);
        mEmailTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pinfoEmail);
        mUsernameTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pinfoUsername);
        mPasswordTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pinfoPassword);

        mContentResolver = AddActivity.this.getContentResolver();

        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isValid()){
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); //Content Values Class is used to store a set of values that the ContentResolver can process.
                    values.put(PInfoContract.PInfoColumns.PINFO_WEBSITE, mWebsiteTextView.getText().toString()); //.put add values ot the set & .toString() to convert it to the right format
                    values.put(PInfoContract.PInfoColumns.PINFO_EMAIL, mEmailTextView.getText().toString());
                    values.put(PInfoContract.PInfoColumns.PINFO_USERNAME, mUsernameTextView.getText().toString());
                    values.put(PInfoContract.PInfoColumns.PINFO_PASSWORD, mPasswordTextView.getText().toString());

                    Uri returned = mContentResolver.insert(PInfoContract.URI_TABLE, values);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "record id returned is; " + returned);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AddActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish(); //always use this when the activity's process is finished
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please make sure you have inputted valid data.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean isValid(){ //You can have this as complex as you want. Like checking other databases or number of charas.
        if(mWebsiteTextView.getText().toString().length() == 0 ||
                mEmailTextView.getText().toString().length() == 0 ||
                mUsernameTextView.getText().toString().length() == 0 ||
                mPasswordTextView.getText().toString().length() == 0 ){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean someDataEntered(){
        if(mWebsiteTextView.getText().toString().length() > 0 ||
                mEmailTextView.getText().toString().length() > 0 ||
                mUsernameTextView.getText().toString().length() > 0 ||
                mPasswordTextView.getText().toString().length() > 0 ){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(someDataEntered()){
            PInfoDialog dialog = new PInfoDialog();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(PInfoDialog.DIALOG_TYPE, PInfoDialog.CONFIRM_EXIT); //This method places a text string in the virtual screen at the specified location.
            dialog.setArguments(args);
            dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "confirm-exit");
        } else{
            super.onBackPressed(); //if someDataEntered() is false just do what usually happnes.
        }
    }
}
```

logcat:

> 06-23 16:03:14.117  21940-21940/com.example.saleh.findmypassword E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.example.saleh.findmypassword.PInfoProvider
>   06-23 16:03:14.121  21940-21940/com.example.saleh.findmypassword W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c95b20)
>   06-23 16:03:14.121  21940-21940/com.example.saleh.findmypassword E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.saleh.findmypassword, PID: 21940
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.example.saleh.findmypassword.PInfoProvider/pinfos
>               at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1186)
>               at com.example.saleh.findmypassword.AddActivity$1.onClick(AddActivity.java:51)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> The manifest:

``````
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.saleh.findmypassword.provider.READWRITE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="Personal Info">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".AddActivity"
        android:label="@string/add_pinfo_title"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.saleh.findmypassword.MainActivity" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.example.saleh.findmypassword.EditActivity"
        android:label="@string/edit_pinfo_title"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.saleh.findmypassword.MainActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.saleh.findmypassword.SearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/search_pinfo_title"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.saleh.findmypassword.MainActivity" />
    `````
    <provider
        android:name="com.example.saleh.findmypassword.PInfoProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.saleh.findmypassword.provider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:readPermission="com.example.saleh.findmypassword.provider.READWRITE"
        android:writePermission="com.example.saleh.findmypassword.provider.READWRITE" />
</application>
``````

> Here is where the uri is being built:

public class PInfoContract {

```
public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.example.saleh.findmypassword.provider";
public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);

public static final String PATH_PINFOS = "pinfos";
public static final Uri URI_TABLE = Uri.parse(BASE_CONTENT_URI.toString() + "/" + PATH_PINFOS);

public static final String[] TOP_LEVEL_PATHS = {
        PATH_PINFOS
};

public static class PInfos implements PInfoColumns, BaseColumns {
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =
            BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendEncodedPath(PATH_PINFOS).build();
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd." + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + ".pinfos";
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd." + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + ".pinfos";

    public static Uri buildPInfoUri(String PInfoId) {
        return CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendEncodedPath(PInfoId).build();
    }

    public static String getPInfoId(Uri uri) {
        return uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: `UriMatcher` is probably case-sensitive, and you have the wrong case in your `Uri`.

Comment: i think the problem is in the provider package, post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I think uri issue plz change content uri name
Please check Uri name with your package name (Manifest file) com.example.saleh.findmypassword.provider  another reason is add permission for provider (if missing)

Comment: Added some more info.

Comment: change :  public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.example.saleh.findmypassword.PInfoProvider");

Comment: Got this after changing: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.example.saleh.findmypassword.PInfoProvider/pinfos

Comment: hey you don´t have any file called com.example.saleh.findmypassword.provider.java! so you have to change the authorities  : android:authorities="com.example.saleh.findmypassword.PInfoProvider" check all the strings inside your androidmanifest.xml!

Comment: From where did you get the .java in the end?

Comment: And I tried changing the android:authorities to what you gave me but still..

Comment: Any more suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have this exception:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Uri: 
content://com.example.saleh.findmypassword.provider/pinfos at 
com.example.saleh.findmypassword.PInfoProvider.insert(PInfoProvider.java:97>)
```

check the package of your provider, it doesn´t exist (Unknown Uri):

```
com.example.saleh.findmypassword.provider
```

must be:

```
com.example.saleh.findmypassword.PInfoProvider
```

**update:**

change the value of the variable `BASE_CONTENT_URI` to :

```
public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.example.saleh.findmypassword.PInfoProvider");
```

Comment: I added the manifest file. please check it out I don't think I should change the name. PInfoProvider is the name while the authorities is provider. If not then please suggest me anything to do.

Comment: yes you are right! the name is com.example.saleh.findmypassword.PInfoProvider but in some part of your code you are using com.example.saleh.findmypassword.provider as the name of the provider.

Comment: Is there a way to know where exactly?

Comment: Will post the class where the Uri is being built in a sec